# How to search based on multiple column using basic jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, html-table

I am working on table layout with search on top of each row.

https://codepen.io/chiragjain94/pen/rNLBbNG

I want to search for "897" in first column and in second column I want to enter "Card"
The result should be => 553492-987 897 Traveller Card

But that is not the result I get.

```js
$(document).on('input', '.filter-table', function() {
  var searchKey = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
  var tableName = $(this).attr('data-table-id');
  var columnId = $(this).attr('data-column-id');
  $("#" + tableName + " tbody td:nth-child(" + columnId + ")").filter(function() {
    $(this).parent().toggle($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(searchKey) > -1);
  });
});
```

```html
<table class="table mb-0  table-striped" id="selectedList">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2">Table</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="search-fields" style="">
      <td><input type="search" class="form-control search-input filter-table valid" data-table-id="selectedList" data-column-id="1" placeholder="Search column 1..." autocomplete="off"></td>
      <td><input type="search" class="form-control search-input filter-table" data-table-id="selectedList" data-column-id="2" placeholder="Search column 2" autocomplete="off"></td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr class="search-row">
      <td>Card 126 897</td>
      <td>Big Bank 2015</td>
    </tr>

    <tr class="search-row">
      <td>553492-987 897</td>
      <td>Traveller Card</td>
    </tr>

    <tr class="search-row" style="">
      <td>Card 67920</td>
      <td>Credit Card 8729
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>

</table>
```

Additional condition, once I clear any of the search input, my result table should still show result based on other search input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of filtering by comparing each input value separately, you should take both in account. You can do it this way:

```
$(document).on('input', '.filter-table', function () {
 var tableName = $(this).attr('data-table-id');
 var searchKey1 = $("[data-column-id='1']").val().toLowerCase();
 var searchKey2 = $("[data-column-id='2']").val().toLowerCase();


$("#" + tableName + " tbody tr").filter(function () {
 var columnSearch1 = !searchKey1 || 
 $(this).children().eq(0).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(searchKey1) > -1;

 var columnSearch2 = !searchKey2 ||  
 $(this).children().eq(1).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(searchKey2) > -1;

 $(this).toggle(columnSearch1 && columnSearch2);
 });

});
```

[Link to example](https://codepen.io/gabrielmacus/pen/BazBewY)

Comment: Thanks a ton!
This is exactly what I wanted.